# No AWS Credentials provided by WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, amazon-eks

I'm trying to run Spark job via `spark-submit` in EKS Fargate profile.
Job creation:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: data-processor-external-spark-job
  namespace: fargate-profile-selector
  labels:
    app: data-processor
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: data-processor-external-spark
        sdr.appname: spark
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      hostname: data-processor
      serviceAccountName: data-processor
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
      - name: data-processor
        image: <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data-processor:1.0.1-507
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - "spark-submit"
          - "--master"
          - "spark://spark-core:7077"
          - "--verbose"
          - "--class"
          - "com.extraction.DataExtractionJob"
          - "--deploy-mode"
          - "client"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.driver.cores=4"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driver.request.cores=2"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=4"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.executor.cores=4"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=3"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=4"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.executor.instances=1"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.driver.memory=2G"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.executor.memory=3GB"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.driver.supervise=false"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.port.maxRetries=25"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.all.committer.magic.enabled=true"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.container.image=<account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data-processor-scaling:1.0.1-508"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.namespace=fargate-profile-selector"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=data-processor"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName=data-processor"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driver.label.execution_id=c5cfaccb-d934-4150-ac59-471a7b6dac57"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.executor.label.execution_id=c5cfaccb-d934-4150-ac59-471a7b6dac57"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=extract-c5cfaccb-d934-4150-ac59-471a7b6dac57"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=extract-c5cfaccb-d934-4150-ac59-471a7b6dac57"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.executorEnv.AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.executorEnv.AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/data-processor-service-account"
          - "--conf"
          - "spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/data-processor-service-account"
          - "local:///opt/etl.jar"
          - "--spark_master=spark://spark-core:7077"
          - "--trace_id=54321"
          - "--job_execution_id=12213131"
          - "--s3_endpoint=https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
          - "--input_data_uri=s3://uploads-dev/coreattribute.csv"
          - "--output_data_uri=s3://uploads-dev/fargate-test/test-lead/output"
          - "--error_data_uri=s3://uploads-dev/fargate-test/test-lead/error"
          - "--s3_kms_key_id=arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account-id>:key/40859321-de3a-4751-b5c4-44a0378a17c0"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          - containerPort: 40000
          - containerPort: 40001
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: data-processor-secrets
        env:
          - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
            value: regional
          - name: S3_KMS_KEY_ID
            value: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account-id>:key/40859321-de3a-4751-b5c4-44a0378a17c0
          - name: SPARK_PROMETHEUS_METRICS_REPORTING_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: KUBERNETES_API
            value: https://<id>.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
          - name: SPARK_DRIVER_CORES_REQUEST
            value: "2"
          - name: SPARK_DRIVER_CORES_LIMIT
            value: "4"
          - name: SPARK_MEMORY_OVERHEAD_FACTOR
            value: "0.4"
          - name: SPARK_MEMORY_OVERHEAD
            value: "1.0"
          - name: CONNECTOR_MOUNT_PATH
            value: /etc/secrets/connector
          - name: S3_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: S3_PATH_STYLE_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: SPARK_MASTER_HOST
            value: spark-core
          - name: DATA_PROCESSOR_HOST
            value: data-processor
          - name: SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY
            value: 2G
          - name: SPARK_DRIVER_CORES
            value: "4"
          - name: ZOOKEEPER_HOST
            value: zookeeper
          - name: ZOOKEEPER_PORT
            value: "2181"
          - name: SPARK_CLUSTER_NODES
            value: "6"
          - name: SPARK_CLUSTER_NODE_MEMORY_GB
            value: "24"
          - name: SPARK_CLUSTER_NODE_CORES
            value: "12"
          - name: SPARK_UNZIP_CORES_LIMIT
            value: "18"
          - name: SPARK_UNZIP_MEMORY_GB_LIMIT
            value: "18"
          - name: SPARK_UNION_CORES_LIMIT
            value: "12"
          - name: SPARK_UNION_MEMORY_GB_LIMIT
            value: "24"
          - name: SPARK_JOIN_CORES_LIMIT
            value: "12"
          - name: SPARK_JOIN_MEMORY_GB_LIMIT
            value: "32"
          - name: SPARK_EXPORT_CORES_LIMIT
            value: "12"
          - name: SPARK_EXPORT_MEMORY_GB_LIMIT
            value: "24"
          - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
            value: data-processor
          - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            value: us-west-2
          - name: AWS_REGION
            value: us-west-2
          - name: AWS_ROLE_ARN
            value: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/data-processor-service-account
          - name: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
            value: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
        volumeMounts:
          - name: secrets
            mountPath: /etc/secrets
            readOnly: true
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 2Gi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

> aws eks describe-fargate-profile --cluster-name dev-fargate-cluster-poc-2 --fargate-profile-name fargateprofile

```
{
    "fargateProfile": {
        "fargateProfileName": "fargateprofile",
        "fargateProfileArn": "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:<account-id>:fargateprofile/dev-fargate-cluster-poc-2/fargateprofile/60c21523-d172-5442-5548-5ca118185ddf",
        "clusterName": "dev-fargate-cluster-poc-2",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-30T21:04:09.930000+02:00",
        "podExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/dev-fargate-cluster-poc-2-FargateNodeInstanceRole-3QDTOVKG62WU",
        "subnets": [
            "subnet-0371427591c2240ab",
            "subnet-08895c527023616c1",
            "subnet-0b398db79033a2be5"
        ],
        "selectors": [
            {
                "namespace": "fargate-profile-selector",
                "labels": {}
            }
        ],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "tags": {
            "sys_tag_version": "2020-04-29",
            "sys_owner_div": "0056",
            "sys_owner_dept": "4755",
            "sys_sub_env": "dev",
            "sys_app_id": "0",
            "sys_env": "dev",
            "sys_app_name": "cloud-dev-dev-5828"
        }
    }
}
```

> aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name dev-fargate-cluster-poc-2-FargateNodeInstanceRole-3QDTOVKG62WU (AmazonS3FullAccess policy exists)

```
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AISSystemLogsPolicy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:policy/AISSystemLogsPolicy"
        }
    ]
}
```

> kubectl describe serviceaccount data-processor

```
Name:                data-processor
Namespace:           fargate-profile-selector
Labels:              app=data-processor
                     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                     chart=data-processor-0.0.1-366
                     heritage=Helm
                     release=data-processor
Annotations:         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/data-processor-service-account
                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: data-processor
                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: fargate-profile-selector
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   data-processor-token-2cfhr
Tokens:              data-processor-token-2cfhr
Events:              <none>
```

> aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name data-processor-service-account (AmazonS3FullAccess policy exists)

```
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "kms-key",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:policy/kms-key"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "msk-admin-policy",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:policy/msk-admin-policy"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "NoDeleteOnGPG",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:policy/NoDeleteOnGPG"
        }
    ]
}
```

S3 config from codebase perspective:

```
    val s3ProviderClasses = Seq(classOf[WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider],
      classOf[TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider],
      classOf[SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider],
      classOf[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider],
      classOf[IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider])
      .map(_.getName)
      .mkString(",")

  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", s3Conf.s3Endpoint)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", s3Conf.s3TlsEnabled.toString)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", "15000")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout", "60000")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.timeout", "120000")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.attempts.maximum", "10")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.threads.max", "500")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.multipart.size", "256M")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.multipart.threshold", "5G")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer", "disk")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", s3Conf.s3PathStyleEnabled.toString)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("fs.s3a.impl.disable.cache", false)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", s3ProviderClasses)
  s3Conf.s3KmsKeyId.foreach { kmsKeyId =>
    log.info(s"S3 SSE-KMS encryption is enabled for $appName job. KMS Key ID: $kmsKeyId")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "SSE-KMS")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption.key", kmsKeyId)
  }
```

Error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3://uploads-dev/coreattribute.csv: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

I'm expecting, that `WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider` is being used, instead of `SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider`.
`WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider` has to be used, because there is at least serviceaccount `data-processor` with role `data-processor-service-account` which has full S3 access.

So, why does it expect `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` variables, despite the fact that container is running by service account with full access to S3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

no s3a support for WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider in ASF releases as of hadoop-aws <= 3.3.5. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-18154 for a PR if you want to set this up. That PR is still awaiting an update, if you want to take it on and wrap it up -you are strongly encouraged to do so, especially if you can rerun the entire hadoop-aws integration tests using the new provider.

Open source development depends on contributions from developers to add the features they need. Now is your opportunity to contribute!